# ant <cvs date problem for checkout

Tags: ant, cvs

```
<cvs cvsroot="${repository}" command="checkout" package="${package.name}"
        date="${cvs.name}" dest="${dest.dir}" failonerror="true" />
```

and in date i can enter "alala" but i will still get code from cvs.

How can i prevent this and what is the correct date format for date tag? I think i always get the same code, never code for example from 2008/06/25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this link](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/wiki/CVS--Concurrent%20Versions%20System%20v1.12.12.1%3A%20Guide%20to%20CVS%20commands#SEC121) for date input formats.  I guess "2008-06-25" should work or "06/25/2008".